# On my Mazda 2 (2011 Black model) The door open light is staying on and will not lock

Tags: electrical, mazda

On my Mazda 2 (Black model 2011) The door open light on the dash is on despite all 5 doors being properly shut and will not lock on the remote or the key because it thinks a door is still open.
Could this be a problem with one or all door shut sensors. 
Has anyone experienced this and or can recommend a solution.

Comment: Welcoming me to the site. Does the dome light stay on as well?

Comment: Has anything been done to it recently as far as electrical work. Also if something was done on the doors (e.g. Audio or lock work) someone could *in theory* have disconnected a switch.

Comment: Are you 100% the trunk lid is shut?   I had similar problem and that was it, the latch didn't fully seat so just pushing it didnt work I had to open and slam shut again.